# Regex help needed for QueryString in XML

Tags: xml, regex

I'm working on implementing a regex pattern in XML, the issue I'm facing is when checking for ampersand in XML. Is there any cleaner way of doing this, the parameters can be of different order.

```
request_id=123&application_id=876734&cat_id=1234&rept_id=12123&req_type=Schedule&lookid=GH123366HJ123&access_key=ABCD12345&requested_date=2012-02-05 04:50:17&run_date=2012-02-05 04:50:17&schedule_id=1123
```

The corresponding regex written is

```
<filter regex="request_id=([^&amp;]+)&amp;application_id=([^&amp;]+)&amp;cat_id=    ([^&amp;]+)&amp;rept_id=([^&amp;]+)&amp;req_type=([^&amp;]+)&amp;lookid=([^&amp;]+)&amp;access_key=([^&amp;]+)&amp;requested_date=([^&amp;]+)&amp;run_date=([^&amp;]+)&amp;schedule_id=([^&amp;]+)" source="get-property('To')"/>
```

My application (*I do not have control in changing the way it works*) would read the regex pattern from the XML and validate the query string.

**Note: Right now it is not working as expected.**

Alternate solution I found is

```
([^?=&amp;]+)(=([^&amp;].*))
```

However it does not solve my purpose.

Comment: Which regex engine? Which language?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want to replace the content between = and &,here is the code in c#

```
string s="request_id=123&application_id=87....................";
Regex r=new Regex(@"(?<=\=).*?(?=(\&)|\z)");
r.Replace(s,"([^&amp;]+)&amp;");
```

You can then add `<filter regex=` and `source="get-property('To')"/>` to the new replaced string!